# Save panel or Form as image with High quality

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently using this code to screen capture the panel I created, but whenever I am saving it, the quality is bad. Is there any way to maintain the good quality when saving it?

I tried resizing the panel but the result is still the same.
I tried doing a normal screen shot with the snipping tool and it also has the same result with the codes I use.

Any suggestions? or help?

```
private void SaveControlImage(Control theControl)
{
    snapCount++;

    int width = panel1.Size.Width;
    int height = panel1.Size.Height;

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb);

    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
    //bm.Save(@"D:\TestDrawToBitmap.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

    bm.Save(deskTopPath + @"/Offer_" + snapCount.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + @".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

---

Like here, it looks pixelated if you compare it to what you're reading now (like this website). I tried to screen cap the form but it looks like the uploaded picture so its useless

Screenshot:

[image: 1]

Comment: maybe try something like supersampling and multiply your width and height by some factor i would suggest around 4-16. Not sure if it will scale or actually render the control in higher resolution but its worth a try.

Comment: `I tried doing a normal screen shot with the snipping tool and it also has the same result with the codes I use` > Do you mean that a screenshot of your form already looks bad? Then is it maybe the form itself that already "looks bad"? I mean unless you save the screenshot in a lossy format any screenshot of your form should actually look exactly like your form is displayed on the screen...

Comment: Describe what do you men by '*bad quality*'. The form *(captured)* should be the same quality as it is displayed on monitor. Of course, this quality is bad for printing, but that is different story. You can not do anything with this unless you make a really big form and size it down *(not reduce pixels, only the size)*, after it was captured. But make the form bigger *(including all fonts and images, etc)* is not simple.

Comment: I tried adjusting the width and height of the image, but still it's not giving me the "normal" quality of the image. Feels like bitmap works like snipping tool, because it also gives me low quality image.

Comment: @KennethChang Can you add some screenshots? (Plus the results of course)

Comment: @Julo its like it is pixelated, I tried resizing the form/fonts to the huge size for testing but still it does not screen cap to the normal quality

Comment: How do you observe the resulting image? I hope you aren't looking in fullscreen at something 200x200 size. What **is** in this panel? Maybe it's low quality there already.

Comment: @Sinatr I checked the quality of the text in my form and compare it to the screenshot of it.

Comment: *"quality of the text"* - closer now, what produce this text? Is it another control? Screenshot would really shine here.

Comment: @KennethChang the pixelation *(in view mode 100%)* should be the same in image and on monitor when the form is displayed. When you see the image in 200% or more, ot print it on paper, of course you see pixelation. This is the way how pixel graphics works. The forms are not vectorized.

Comment: @Julo I guess there is no hope then, because I am trying to create a small program that creates an image out of a template

Comment: @Sinatr screenshot in the answers

Comment: You are asking for a solution to a problem that does not have one.  Monitors are low resolution devices and the OS uses lots of tricks to make them look better.  Anti-aliasing of text is especially notable, ClearType is pretty universal.  That only ever works well when such text is displayed back onto a monitor at the *exact* same resolution.  So trying to enlarge the image, or showing it on a different device (like a printer) is not going to end well.  Feature, not a bug.  Only re-rendering the content is a solution, you can fix a Paint event handler.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I guess there are limitations to whatever i'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried the .png format? If compression model is a better fit for this kind of bitmaps.

Comment: A screenshot contains text and must therefore never be saved as jpg, which is only for photgraphs. Use png instead. Also: Text on screen is usually anti-aliased to make it look smother. Sometimes this will not look as good when taken out of context and enlarged..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use to save a screenshot:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
private void SaveControlAsImage(Control control, string path)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, control.Bounds);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        /* using ImageFormat.Png or ImageFormat.Bmp saves the image with better quality */
        bitmap.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

[Control screenshot using Windows Snipping Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B58J4.png)

[Control screenshot using SaveControlAsImage (ImageFormat.Png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZcQ.png)

[Control screenshot using SaveControlAsImage (ImageFormat.Jpeg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf9Vw.jpg)

It's not the best quality (just a little blurry), but this removes the distortion around the text and keeps the right color.

Sidenote: You're not using the parameter (`theControl`) passed to your method, so you might as well remove it (not recommended), or change all the calls to `panel1` inside the method to `theControl` and call the method like

```
this.SaveControlImage(this.panel1);
```

Also, when you're accessing just a property (i.e. `this.panel1.Size.Width`) it's better to just call the property instead of assign it to a variable. If you're calling a method and getting a value back (which you'll be using more than once), you must assign it to a variable (i.e. `int arrayCount = array.Count()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(controls.Width, controls.Height-50, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics Grap = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

Grap.CopyFromScreen(PointToScreen(controls.Location).X, PointToScreen(controls.Location).Y, 0, 0, AnhDoThi.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg";
DialogResult tl = save.ShowDialog();
if (tl == DialogResult.OK)
{
    bmp.Save(save.FileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Completed !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is not using vector graphics to draw the user interface. Therefore, all you can get generically is to draw the control to a Bitmap instead of to the screen. This works independently of whether your control is visible on the screen, but there is not more than that. If you want a higher-resolution image from a Windows Forms control, the only way is to resize the control and hope that it supports zooming.